Is my implementation of Tanstack Query correct?
Am I doing the right thing about implementing my the tanstack query into my system?

const getUsers = async (page = 1, searchQuery?: string): Promise<UserData> => {
  const url = new URL(`fetch-api`);
  url.searchParams.append("curPage", page.toString());
  if (searchQuery) url.searchParams.append("query", searchQuery);

  const response = await fetch(url.toString(), {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  });

  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);

  return response.json();
};

export default function Page({ searchParams }: PageProps) {
  const currentPage = Number(searchParams?.curPage) || 1;
  const { search, setSearch } = useUserStore();

  const { data, isLoading } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["users", currentPage, search], 
    queryFn: () => getUsers(currentPage, search),
  });

  const filteredItems =
    data?.items?.filter((user) =>
      user.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
      user.email.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    ) || [];

My code is working but I don't know if I am using tanstack query at its full potential maybe I can refactor a code or improve. I just want to get an opinion from you guys on how I can implement it better than my current code. Thank you!

If you have working code that you want peer-reviewed, your question belongs on [codereview.se], which was created specifically for that purpose. Be sure and read the guidelines before posting there, as they have specific requirements. This site is for questions related to non-working (problem) code. Also, you'll find your experiences here will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

This question might be better for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Before posting on Code Review please read A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users and How do I ask a good question? first.
